# Error as soon as I add setOnClickListener Android Studio

Tags: java, android

so for a school project I'm making an app, but I"m stuck.
I've got a button on my main class.
XML code of this class:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.larsb.csvvg.Home"
    android:background="@drawable/home">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Lariks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Salland"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Lariks"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Lariks"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Lariks" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/CSG"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Salland"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Salland"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Salland" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So what I want to do is when I button click Lariks I switch to a new activity.
I try to do this with the following code:

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int WELCOME=4000;
    Button lariks;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lariks = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Lariks);
        lariks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
        
            }
        });
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Home.class );
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        },WELCOME);

    }

}
```

In the public void onClick(view) thing I got the code for switching activity, that's not the problem.
The problem is that as soon as I add the:

```html
lariks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

the app can't launch anymore. It starts the emulator but it keeps saying the app has stopped. Anyone has any idea why this is? If I remove that part of the code the app actually does run.

Comment: Add the stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

Your `Button` with `android:id="@+id/Lariks"` is not in the `activity_main` layout (as evidenced by `tools:context="com.example.larsb.csvvg.Home"` and your crash). Therefore `findViewById(R.id.Lariks)` returns null, and attempting to call `setOnClickListener()` on this null reference causes a crash.

Your `findViewById()`-`setOnClickListener()` pair should likely be in the `Home` activity, or the button should be in the `activity_main` layout.